# How do I avoid name conflict when defining @Bean in an abstract class?

Tags: java, spring

I want to have something like this:

```java
public class AbstractHandler {
    @Bean
    protected abstract RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route();
}
```

```java
public class SomeHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
        // defining some route
    }
}
```

```java
public class AnotherHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
        // defining another route
    }
}
```

I want every subclass to have its own bean. However, the code above results in a name conflict, as both beans would have the same name (because the bean takes name from a method).

It is possible to annotate the method with `@Bean("uniqueNameHere")` in each sub-class but it is a little annoying, sometimes I forget to add this annotation and it results in a bug.

I thought about something like specifying an additional abstract method in the abstract class and using this method for getting a bean name somehow. However, I did not find a way to do so.

So is there any way to make every implementation of an abstract class have a bean of its own without adding a `@Bean` annotation in each of them?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need your bean methods to be overriding an abstract method?

Comment: this is kind of a weird thing to do - `@Bean` configurations are defined in a `@Configuration` class which usually doesn't have subchildren. Normal way of going at it would be to define several Beans with different names and autowire them in each of the subclasses with the correct `@Qualifier`

Comment: I use reactive functional endpoints here, so this is basically a way to define an endpoint. I do not need to autowire them anywhere later, they just must be registered

Comment: It's OK to have an abstract base but "normally" one would place the `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations on the derived classes since they are the ones providing the bean: the abstract base just provides common code and/or method contracts.